# momentjs - change format of local time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timezone, momentjs

I am using moment to get the time. I am getting it in format: Thu Feb 21 2019 10:44:21 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time). However, I need it in format 03:44:21PM. Can anyone please tell me how I can achieve that using momentjs?

Comment: `moment().format('hh:mm:ssA')`

Comment: This returns me 10:44:21. The offset of 5 hours is not added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `momentjs` for this purpose. `moment().format()`

```
moment().format('hh:mm:ss A')
```

For more details visit [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Local can also be used to convert out of a fixed offset mode:

```
moment.parseZone('2016-05-03T22:15:01+02:00').local().format('hh:mm:ss A');
```

Comment: Please see my comment on tholle's answer.

Comment: Local can also be used to convert out of a fixed offset mode:

moment.parseZone('2016-05-03T22:15:01+02:00').local().format('hh:mm:ss A');

Answer (score 0):

Get your TimeZone and convert your timezone using this:

```
let timeZone = moment.tz.guess();
let date = 'Thu Feb 21 2019 10:44:21 GMT+0500' // input date (other timezone)
let convertDate = moment(date).tz(timeZone) //converted Time
```

Comment: I am getting this error: "Cannot read property 'guess' of undefined"

Comment: Try this:
  let timeZone = moment.tz.setDefault(moment.tz.guess());

Comment: @Eren555 make sure that you import moment properly. With es6 it goes from `import moment from 'moment'` to `'import moment from 'moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data'`.